# Mayhem with partitions and GPT: mdadm RAID overwritten by Windows partition - possible to fix partition table?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, raid, mdadm

dear Community,

I’m writing as I may have wrecked my system up.
I launched disk manager in Windows; as one of my disks was not recognized, and as Windows kindly suggested me to initialize the-said disk, I clicked on « **initialize with GPT** » - as I thought it was a USB key which was not mounting.

Unfortunately, **it was my RAID 5 volume created with mdadm**…

So if I understood well, **Windows created a GPT partition to replace (?) the existing one mdadm created**. Now I can see this RAID disk on Windows, which was not the case before.

Without having touched anything, **do you think I can revert back the partition?** Any guidance on how to do it?

Any help very very much appreciated!

EDIT 24/06/2023: Thanks for the first answers! I do have backups but not images of the full disks (only at file level, and not everything). **I try to check if there is a way to rewrite partition table first** (if possible! and how…) to make mdadm work again with existing data, then trying to recover data on the disks themselves (but as it is RAID 5 I predict a lovely mess, isn’t it?), and last resort to just wipe everything and use backed up data (but this is not a challenge nor would be a question here :) ).

(As a bonus, **here are the results of some commands** (my RAID is mounted under md126, with 3 disks: sda, sdc and sdd - sdb is the storage for OS:

——— PARTED ————

```
#parted -l

Error: Argument invalide during seek for read on /dev/sda
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel? o
Model: ATA TOSHIBA DTO1ACA3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA TOSHIBA HDWD130 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Error: /dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label
Mode1: ATA TOSHIBA HDWD130 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknoun
Disk Flags:

Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md126: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number    Start    End        Size     File system   Name                            Flags
1        17,4kB    16,8MB    16,8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition    msftres
```

——— GDISK ———

```
# gdisk /dev/md126

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.6

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/md126: 11721056256 sectors, 5.5 TiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 84059E0C-5A54-40A5-A643-39FASFFA047E
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 11721056222
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 11721023455 sectors (5.5 TiB)

Number     Start (sector)     End (sector)     Size        Code     Name
  1          34                 32767          16.0 MiB    0C01     Microsoft reserved...
```

——— MDSTAT ———

```
# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sda[2] sdc[1] sdd[0]
      5860528128 blocks super external:/md127/0 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 0 [3/3] [UUU]

md127 : inactive sdc[2](S) sda[1](S) sdd[0](S)
      7560 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Easiest way: diff the damaged drive with the last full image, and restore what was overwritten. Safest way: back up any data since last disk images, restore images, restore recent data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the answers! I edited my question - I don’t have full disk backup (only partial file-level backups), and I use RAID 5, where anyhow I need to rebuild the array then put the data to make everything work - without guidance this is outside of my knowledge :’(

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thanks for the answers! I edited my question - as I use RAID 5 I am unsure I can get anything else than scrambled data with this, but I will give a try if no other option and if you think it is the best way to proceed!

Comment: TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software: certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.   https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: @vssher wow thanks, it may do the trick! I didn’t stumbled upon this - I will try it today and let you know :)